# How to gain root on BlueStacks Android emulator

Tags: rooting, bluestacks, emulators

[BlueStacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) is a popular Android emulator for Windows and macOS for gamers. It is popular, because the emulator ships with Google Play Store pre-installed and installing any games is easy. Unfortunately, the emulator file system is not rooted by default. How to root it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These instructions require that you understand the UNIX command line basics. The instructions work on OSX, Linux and Windows. No Microsoft Windows or BlueStacks Tweaker needed.

The emulator is internally using VirtualBox and runs Android x64 binaries (64 bit). It ships with two VirtualBox VDI disk images, `Prebundled.bdi` and `Root.vdi`. Luckily BlueStacks has left a primitive `su` binary on the disk image, so we do not need to add this binary to the image ourselves. We still need to change VirtualBox settings, though.

`adb` command can be obtained from Android Studio SDK by Google or it is also found in `/Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/MacOS/adb`.

Make sure that the emulator is off and turn all disks in VirtualBox configuration file to read-write. On macOS, the file can be found `~/Library/BlueStacks/Android/Android.vbox`. Make sure the emulator is not running when you edit this file.

[image]

Start the emulator.

Enable ADB bridge in the emulator settings.

[image]

Download [SuperSU zip](https://supersuroot.org/downloads/SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip) file on your local computer.

Start your ADB hacking session.

```
# This is the default port exposed by BlueStacks
adb connect localhost:5555
```

Push the zip file to the `/mnt/sdcard` of the emulated device.

```
adb push SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip /mnt/sdcard
```

Then work inside the emulator shell:

```
# Start shell session in the emulator VM
adb shell
```

```
# Use the provided BlueStacks binary to switch to root  
system/xbin/bstk/su

# Disable SELinux
setenforce 0

# Remount all filesystems
mount -o rw,remount,rw /
mount -o rw,remount,rw /system
mount -o rw,remount,exec,rw /storage/emulated

# Unzip SuperSU zip
cd /mnt/sdcard
mkdir supersu
cd supersu
unzip ../SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip

# Extract su command and run its post-install
cp x64/su /system/xbin/su 
chmod a+rwx /system/xbin/su 
/system/xbin/su --install

# Start su daemon mode
/system/xbin/su --daemon
```

Now run the installer for Superuser.apk in the emulator through Media Manager.

[image]

[image]

When `su --daemon` is running SuperSU Android UI should detect the root when started:

[image]

The emulator needs to be restarted after this as it hangs. After the restart, when opening SuperSU you see it is enabled.

[image]

Comment: I got this error `cp: /system/xbin/su: Read-only file system` when I ran `cp x64/su /system/xbin/su`. i followed all of the steps up to that point. How can I fix this?

Comment: Some of the earlier steps have failed and Virtualbox did not mount the disk in write mode.

Comment: Something's wrong with the SuperSu zip. It doesn't extract and VirusTotal doesn't like it for some kind of ad aware library. I'd recommend checking on that and ensuring a safe binary is used instead.

Comment: mounting of /system fails. I too am getting Read-only file system. Anyway to bypass this?

Comment: I just found out in latest build they removed `su` access. now I get permission denied for su. I did kind of work around. Mounted `Root.vdi` under Library/Bluestacks/android into ubuntu vm via virtualbox. Added the files manually. changed their permission to 1000:1000 and tried 2000:2000 but did not got it to work. `only position independent executables` on super su. also tried busybox's su but no luck yet. I copied bstk su to other location. It works but gives output 1 and gives back `shell` user again. :(

Comment: may also (instead?) need to change a `"ReadOnly"` from `true` to `false` in bluestacks's `HypervVm.json`

Comment: Using the latest version of BlueStacks5 I ran into a few changes.  1) The file name to edit for read/write is now named Android.bstk.in.  2) I also had to change HyperVm.json (thanks amgg).  3) /mnt/sdcard is not accessible in any way.  I simply used /sdcard instead. 4) telling people to randomly search for "SuperUser.apk" is not a good idea.  Lots of garbage comes up.  Tell people to find "SuperSU free".

Answer (score 1):

[Mikko Ohtamaa's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/224120/44325) already covered the main question. However, if there are some difficulties while following it, here are some additional tips that may help:

a) If `adb connect localhost:5555` doesn't work, try `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`

b) Usually the .zip file SuperUser..... is a directory, if so, I suggest avoiding these steps

```
mkdir supers
cd supersu
unzip ../SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip*
```

c) Try to find the `SuperUser.apk` on the internet. Then run

*Exit from `adb` and begin from the first step*

*All steps are similar but*

`adb push <SuperUser.apk just got from internet> /mnt/sdcard`

*Avoid these steps*

**#1. Unzip SuperSU zip**

```
cd /mnt/sdcard
mkdir supersu
cd supersu
unzip ../SuperSU-v2.82-201705271822.zip
```

**#2. Extract su command and run its post-install**

```
cp x64/su /system/xbin/su
chmod a+rwx /system/xbin/su
/system/xbin/su --install
```

**#Continue with the next steps**

Then run the `SuperUser.apk` you got from the internet from the step where says run `SuperUser.apk` from MediaCenter.